# How to ensure the messages has been processed by all subscriptions in azure service bus

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, servicebus

Since azure service bus has limitation in message size(256 kb), I am storing a long message in blob and when function app received a message, i am downloading the content from blob storage and converting it to message format.

Once the service bus processed the message successfully, I need to delete the file from blob storage since it is no longer needed.

But the problem here is, Same messages have been sent to two subscriptions under the same topic, One is processed by function app and another one is processed by web job. If i delete the file from blob in function app, then it will not available to webjob and vice versa.

**So is there any way to identify that the message has been processed successfully by all the subscribers?**

Comment: Are you able to add custom properties to the message?

Comment: I don't know if there is "right answer" here, I would probably make a database/storage table where I would mark completions and then have some scheduled function that checks that table and deletes related blobs if all processors have completed.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Servicebus messaging provides us a way of adding [custom or user properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/message-headers-and-properties) to the servicebus message.So

```
1.You can add a custom property like messageReceptionCount to your message with initial value as 0 and send it to your topic.
2.While receiving the message in your topic subscription, you can increment the messageReceptionCount by 1.
3.When the messageReceptionCount has reached the number of subscriptions in the topic you can delete it from your blob storage.
```

I hope this will work fine for you.